# Подсказки css-свойств/значений для sass в VS Code

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code

Работаю в VS Code, пишу стили в *.sass и не показываются подсказки как в файлах *.css. Установленные расширения:
- Sass (syler.sass-indented)
- Beautify css/sass/scss/less
- Live Sass Compiler

Можете подсказать что нужно установить или прописать в настройках?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне кажется для sass нет решения, только  для scss

Comment: Жаль, казалось бы полезная вещь..

Comment: если перейдете на scss, то для него есть плагин SCSS IntelliSense

Comment: Благодарю, для scss всё нормально работает, но мне как-то в sass удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

Плагин так и называется - "Sass". У меня стоит версия 1.8.3 и все прекрасно работает. 
После установки, в поле "Select Language Mode"(в правом нижнем углу) необходимо выбрать "Sass"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]